# quill editor is not displaying the html string

Tags: angular, quill

I am new to angular and using quill editor in my angular app and I am using it to allow users to write HTML code and rendering the HTML code coming from backend and I am previewing that HTML in a separate div but unfortunately the quill editor isn't rendering any HTML code or any text in the editor. it is blank and getting `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` error in console. Any kind of help would be appreciated. thank you

```js
public aboutOptions = { placeholder: "Enter About Text...", modules: false, theme: 'snow', format:'text' };

about:string = '<h1> hello world </h1>'


 onTxtEditorCreated(quill) {
    var toolbar = quill.getModule('toolbar');
    toolbar.addHandler('image', this.imageHandlerMain);
    this.txtQuill = quill;
       this.txtQuill.setContents(this.txtQuill.clipboard.convert(this.about));
  }
```

```html
 <quill-editor id="about" name="about" [options]="aboutOptions" (ready)="onTxtEditorCreated($event)"  required [(ngModel)]="about">
 </quill-editor>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quill-editor-xtsjvi)

if you didn't install

```
 npm install @dimpu/ngx-quill --save
```

in html use

```
<ngx-quill #editor  [modules]="modules"  [(ngModel)]="about" ></ngx-quill>
```

in component declare your models

```
about:string = '<h1> hello world </h1>'
  modules = {
    toolbar: [      
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['formula'], 
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  };
```

If you bind directly string with html tag, quil converts it.

```
replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
    return string.split(search).join(replace);
  }
```

replace your html string wiht code like

```
this.about=this.replaceAll(this.about, "<","&lt;")
```

Comment: your demo isn't displaying `<h1> hello world </h1>` in editor. I want that to display in the editor.

Comment: Updated answer @Prem

Comment: I want the entire string `<h1> hello world </h1>` to be displayed in editor not only `hello world`.